# Can I compare a file in the Java Cache to the file in the App Server?

Tags: java, caching

I have an application in the Application Server that can be installed by any Client PC. I want to know, once the App was installed in the Client Java Cache, Is there a way I can access a file inside the Clients Java Cache to compare to the Application Server? This file controls the version no of the application.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: About what kind of file are we talking here? But yes sure you can access the data. However it would be far easier if the application would just send the version number to the server

Comment: The file is text file (version.txt). How can I access it in the Clients Java cache?

Comment: Thaaaank you #Alexander Heim for the answer, and I still have a question, this sending of app version number to the server? Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: The design was, the downloaded application was a JAR file, once the download was complete it stays in the Java Cache, the only thing I can think of as of now is to read the "version.txt" in the JAR found in the Clients Java Cache to be compare to the Server. But still I dont know how to get this version.txt in the JAR stored in the Java Cache. :P